# UICollectionView with full page cells VS UIScrollView with child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a ViewController which would have swipe-able (android like tabs) pages. These pages themselves will have scrollviews(vertical) inside them and multiple views which would be added dynamically depending on  type of response (different network calls for each page). I can't use a PageViewController as I want the pages to take up only half the screen.

Issues with CollectionView -

- If the cells would get reused (or removed from memory), how would I maintain the state of the cell's UI and store that data (especially difficult for views as each page might have different type of view in them)

Issues with ScrollView -

- I'm worried if there would be memory issues if all page view controllers would be in memory with each view in it

PS - data in each page would be 4-10 stackviews each containing 2-10 images/labels OR just one collectionview

PSS - Total number of tabs wouldn't exceed 10, minimum would be 1

Comment: Have you thought about using CoreData to keep track of the data you'd like?

Comment: @Nickolans Keeping track of data isn't the difficult part, each page would create different type of views depending on the different types of response they get, so if I use a collectionview then I would have to remove all subviews in scrollview and create them again with all the data I stored.

Comment: Use PageViewController  ?. For  your child view controller you can think different  methods to handle memory issues like load thumb image or you can use collectionview / tableview instead of stackview there

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Can't use a PageViewController because I don't want the pages to take the whole screen(check question). Can't use collectionview inside the pages because the views in each block(stack) are very different from each other. They may be similar across pages but not in the same page.

Comment: I think your stated issue with CollectionView is not an issue but exactly how you should approach it. Manage your data(source) well  and draw your UI based on the data you have. The concept of cell reuse is precisely meant for those cases. Developers should not use cells (or other UI elements) as their data storage.

Comment: @AuRis Yes it's not an issue exactly to create it as a CollectionView but then I would have to remove all the views on prepareForReuse every time and then create the views again. So removing and creating a lot of views every time a user swipes seems like the wrong way to go forward. Imagine if the user keeps on scrolling from page 1 to page 10.

Comment: If your cells are so different from each other then create a subclass for each of them. Or store them as variables. Somewhere in my code I have a cell where I load a map, in that case I don't want it to be reused or reinitialized, so I store it in a `var`.

Comment: @AuRis If I store my pages as variables then its the same thing as creating a scrollview with child view controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd implemented it with **collectionView** cause it should be really more resource effective. But then we need to cache states of view controllers. Here is the example

Let's say you have controller `A` which contains collectionView with cell with your child controllers. Then in cell for row

```
....
var childrenVC: [Int: UIViewController] = [:]
....
// cell for row
let cell: ChildControllerCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
if let childController = childrenVC[indexPath.row] {
   cell.contentView.addSubview(childController.view)
   childController.view.frame = cell.contentView.frame
} else {
   let childViewController = ChildViewController()
   addChildViewController(childViewController)
   childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
   cell.contentView.addSubview(childController.view)
   childController.view.frame = cell.contentView.frame
   childrenVC[indexPath.row] = childViewController
   cell.childVC = childViewController
}
return cell
....
class ChildControllerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
     var childVC: UIViewController?
     override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        if !contentView.subviews.isEmpty {
            childVC?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            childVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            childVC?.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the only difference between this and the scrollView child controllers is that this would remove the childview controllers from the view on deque and add the whole child back again. It would keep the child vc in memory the whole time ? Would just removing the vc from the view actually help in any way ?

Comment: you can save only data instead of the whole controller to reduce memory usage. And reinitialise it on cellForRow

Comment: But actually I don't think that it will be huge memory usage if you will just save view controllers

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution and the memory difference comes to 15% max, so implementing I guess this is the best option.

Comment: So the collectionview option didnt work as expected. The issue I faced was the cell wasn't getting reused properly (dont know why). Sometimes a cell wouldn't have any child vc or sometimes they would have two. I've implemented the scrollView option and didnt have a drastic memory increase so I think that would be the best solution.

Comment: Hm, I don't know, I had the same situation as you and my solution worked well. And I've just wrote you roughly the same code

Comment: Would a page view controller not be a suitable solution to this?